# Calculo de sobrevida em C

Tags: c

Pesquisando sobre calcular dias de sobrevida de uma pessoa através da diferença de dias encontrei um programa aqui que me serviu de base para isso
então adicionei os cálculos necessários para saber os a quantidade de: horas, minutos segundos, dias, meses, anos.

Acontece o seguinte, tenho a seguinte data abaixo:

```
dias entre 29/03/1987 a 21/12/2017
30 anos, 8 meses 18 dias
diaspassados=11225
```

De acordo com essa [calculadora](https://pt.calcuworld.com/calendarios/calculadora-de-tempo-entre-duas-datas/). Então faço o mesmo *input* no meu programa e ele retorna a seguinte saída abaixo:

```
    Digite data1: 29/03/1987

    Digite data2: 21/12/2017

    30 ano(s) 9 mes(es) e 5 dia(s) de vida
    269400 horas
    16164000 minutos
    969840000 segundos
    374 mes(es)
    11225 dia(s)
    1603 semana(s)
```

Aparentemente, acredito que o cálculo dos meses tem que subtrair pelos dias em excesso, por exemplo: nesta [calculadora](http://vini-brown.zip.net/). Baseando se na mesma data de *input* do comentário acima e do da calculadora ele me retorna 368 meses exatos e meu programa retorna 374.

Eu sei que teria que fazer o seguinte calculo:

```
meses_totais((dias/30)-qtd_dias);
```

Aqui eu subtraio onde vai me dar exatos 368 meses, mas se eu digitar uma data equivalente a 1 ano e 3 meses ele me da problema nos cálculos de dias:

Por exemplo:

```
Digite duas datas no formato DD/MM/YYYY

Digite data1: 29/03/1987

Digite data2: 30/06/1988

1 ano(s) 3 mes(es) e 4 dia(s) de vida
11016 horas
660960 minutos
39657600 segundos
15 mes(es)
459 dia(s)
65 semana(s)
```

Mas a calculadora online me retorna: 1 anos, 3 meses, e 1 dias e 459 dias.
Queria entender onde que ele está dando essa brecha no erro somando dias a mais ou seja meu programa esta dando 3 dias a mais queria entender o porquê.
O quê está faltando nos cálculos para ser algo mais preciso em relação as horas, minutos, segundos, milissegundos, meses, anos, dias e meses a mais decorrente a partir da data de aniversario na quantidade de dias.

```
   int dias(daysDiff(d1,d2)); // diferença entre datas em dias contando anos bisextos

   int idade(dias/365); //idade em anos

   int qtd_dias((dias%365)%30); // qtd dias adicionais a partir do dia de nascimento

   int qtd_meses(((dias%365)/30)); // qtd meses adicionais a partir do mes de nascimento

   int meses_totais(dias/30);

   //int meses_totais((dias/30)-qtd_dias); // total de meses decorridos nos dias - dias a mais 

   int qtd_semanas(dias/7); // qtd semanas total dos dias

   int horas(dias*24); // qtd horas total dos dias

   int minutos(horas*60); // qtd minutos total dos dias

   int segundos(minutos*60); // qtd segundos total dos dias

o programa é este abaixo:

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987562/determining-the-difference-between-dates

    struct Date
    {
     int d, m, y;
    };

    int daysTill(int month)
    {
     int days=0;

     switch(month)
     {
      case 1: days=0; break;

      case 2: days=31; break;

      case 3: days=59; break;

      case 4: days=90; break;

      case 5: days=120; break;

      case 6: days=151; break;

      case 7: days=181; break;

      case 8: days=212; break;

      case 9: days=243; break;

      case 10:days=273; break;

      case 11:days=304; break;

      case 12:days=334; break;
     }

     return days;
    }

    int daysDiff(Date d1, Date d2)
    {
     int dd1=0;
     int dd2=0;
     int y=0;
     int yref=0;

     yref=((d1.y<d2.y) ? d1.y : d2.y);

     for(y=yref;y<d1.y;y++)
     if(__isleap(y))dd1++;

     if(__isleap(d1.y) && d1.m>2) dd1++;

     dd1+=((daysTill(d1.m) + d1.d)+((d1.y - yref) * 365));

     for(y=yref;y<d2.y;y++)
     if(__isleap(y))dd2++;

     if(__isleap(y) && d2.m>2)dd2++;

     dd2+=((daysTill(d2.m) + d2.d)+((d2.y - yref) * 365));

     return abs(dd2-dd1);
    }

int main()
{

 Date d1, d2;

   printf(
          "\n\tDigite duas datas no formato DD/MM/YYYY"
          "\n\n\tDigite data1: "
         );

   scanf("%d/%d/%d",&d1.d,&d1.m,&d1.y);

   printf(
          "\n\tDigite data2: "
         );

   scanf("%d/%d/%d",&d2.d,&d2.m,&d2.y);


   int dias(daysDiff(d1,d2)); // diferença entre datas em dias contando anos bisextos

   int idade(dias/365); //idade em anos

   int qtd_dias((dias%365)%30); // qtd dias adicionais a partir do dia de nascimento

   int qtd_meses(((dias%365)/30)); // qtd meses adicionais a partir do mes de nascimento

   int meses_totais(dias/30);

   //int meses_totais((dias/30)-qtd_dias); // total de meses decorridos nos dias - dias a mais 

   int qtd_semanas(dias/7); // qtd semanas total dos dias

   int horas(dias*24); // qtd horas total dos dias

   int minutos(horas*60); // qtd minutos total dos dias

   int segundos(minutos*60); // qtd segundos total dos dias

   /*
   int segs(dias*86400);
   int horas(segs/3600);
   int minutos((segs-(horas*3600))/60);
   int segundos((segs - (horas * 3600)) - (minutos * 60));
    */

    printf(
           "\n\t%d ano(s) %d mes(es) e %d dia(s) de vida"
           "\n\t%d horas"
           "\n\t%d minutos"
           "\n\t%d segundos"
           "\n\t%d mes(es)"
           "\n\t%d dia(s)"
           "\n\t%d semana(s)\n\n",
           idade,
           qtd_meses,
           qtd_dias,
           horas,
           minutos,
           segundos,
           meses_totais,
           dias,
           qtd_semanas
          );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para aumentar a precisão sugiro você usar variáveis do tipo `float` ou `double` ao invés do `int` que apenas armazena 4 bytes na memoria.

Comment: sim mas primeiro preciso entender o que esta faltando nos calculos o que tenho que incrementar para deixar preciso fora usar variaveis double...